# how to redirect shell script output to java console

Tags: java, shell

I have a shell script which is sending output to console

```
ID=$PPID
echo the process id of the parent of this script is $ID

#fetch the parent of the program which executed this shell
read PID < <(exec ps -o ppid= "$ID")
echo the grand parent id of the script is $PID

read GPID < <(exec ps -o ppid= "$PID")
echo the grand parent id of the script is $GPID


while read -u 4 P; do
 top -c -n 1 -p "$P"
done 4< <(exec pgrep -P "$PID") >&1
```

I am calling this script from java program and trying to display the output on console but only the output of `echo` is appearing. The output of top command is not appearing on the java console.

Here is my java program

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class InformationFetcher {

    public InformationFetcher() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    InformationFetcher informationFetcher = new InformationFetcher();
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
            informationFetcher.getFilePath());
        InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
        printInputStream(in);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

    private static void printInputStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    StringBuffer outBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        outBuffer.append(line);
        outBuffer.append(newLine);
    }
    System.out.println(outBuffer.toString());
    }

    public String getFilePath() {
    return this.getClass().getResource("/idFetcher.sh").getPath();
    }

}
```

output is

```
the process id of the parent of this script is 3721
the grand parent id of the script is 3241
the grand parent id of the script is 3240
```

but it should also display output of top command. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure about that how `top` outputs, but it seems that `top` doesn't send its result to `STDOUT` in a normal way.

However, if you want `top` to send its result to `STDOUT` in a normal way, give it the `-b` option:

```
top -b -n 1
# -b means in batch mode, which outputs to `STDOUT` normally
```